# ref object is possibly undefined in react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, ref, use-ref

I have a section list and i want to implement a solution to auto scroll to a certain section when clicking on a button. To start with i added a ref to my section list but it's giving out an error as `Object is possibly 'undefined'` (I'm using typescript for my app).

```
<SectionList
          sections={groupActivities}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          initialNumToRender={5}
          ref={(component) => {
            this.sectionList = component;    // This is the line i'm getting the error (in 'this')
          }}
          .........
```

And i'm trying to use my ref as follows

```
function scrollToSection() {
    this.sectionList.scrollToLocation({
      sectionIndex: 0,
      itemIndex: 5,
      viewPosition: 1,
      // viewOffset: 50,
    });
  }
```

The documents i have referred states to use the ref like the way i did but i cannot figure out the issue here.

PS:

this is my new code

```
<SectionList
          sections={groupActivities}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          initialNumToRender={5}
          ref={sectionList}
```

And

```
const sectionList = useRef<SectionList>();
  function scrollToSection() {
    sectionList.current?.scrollToLocation({
      sectionIndex: 0,
      itemIndex: 5,
      viewPosition: 1,
    });
  }
```

I'm getting a type error is `ref={sectionList}` line as follows

```
(JSX attribute) ClassAttributes<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>>.ref?: string | ((instance: SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | null) => void) | React.RefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>> | null | undefined
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: SectionListProps<any, DefaultSectionT> | Readonly<SectionListProps<any, DefaultSectionT>>): SectionList<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | null) => void) | RefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>> | null | undefined'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>>'.
        Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
          Type 'SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | null'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | null'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: SectionListProps<any, DefaultSectionT>, context: any): SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>', gave the following error.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | null) => void) | RefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>> | null | undefined'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>>'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(143, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'
index.d.ts(143, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<SectionList<any, DefaultSectionT>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'
```

Comment: What type has `this.sectionList` ?

Comment: Are you using a functional or class-based component? `use-ref` tag implies functional component but you are referencing *some* `this` which will be undefined in functional components. Can you provide a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example so we've better context? BTW you are using an old ref syntax, what documents are you referencing?

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated my question can you please take a look

Comment: I think we'd still need a more complete code example to confirm, but perhaps you just need to provide an initial ref value, `const sectionList = useRef<SectionList>(null);`.